# How to use compress.js for multiple image compression, preview and upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-compression

I have been using [compress.js](https://github.com/fieldchat/client-compress) for single image upload. But, now i want to use this for multiple image uploads.

What i want to achieve is to select multiple image from html input element and then compress it using this library and also preview those compressed images in dynamically generated  tag.

like this:-

`<img id="preview0">
  <img id="preview1">
  <img id="preview2">`
        ....depending on number of image selected.

This is how i was using it for single image upload

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"   id="image">
<img id="preview">
```

```
const options = {
  targetSize: 0.2,
  quality: 0.75,
  maxWidth: 800,
  maxHeight: 600
}

const compress = new Compress(options)
const upload = document.getElementById("image")

upload.addEventListener(
  "change",
  (evt) => {
    const files = [...evt.target.files]
    compress.compress(files).then((conversions) => {
      // Conversions is an array of objects like { photo, info }.
      // 'photo' has the photo data while 'info' contains metadata
      // about that particular image compression (e.g. time taken).

      const { photo, info } = conversions[0]

      console.log({ photo, info })

     // was using this to append to the form data
      newblob = photo.data;

      // Create an object URL which points to the photo Blob data
      const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(photo.data)

      // Set the preview img src to the object URL and wait for it to load
      Compress.loadImageElement(preview, objectUrl).then(() => {
        // Revoke the object URL to free up memory
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
      })
    })
  },
  false
)
```

i have been trying to achieve it from past 2 days.
i tried to run this in a for loop

`<input type="file" accept="image/*"  multiple  id="image">
<div id="" class="col previewdiv"></div>`

```
$(function() {

    var imgPreviewUpld = function(input, divId) {

        if (input.files) {
            var numberOfImages = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {




                $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr({id : "preview"+i, class:"img-fluid"}).css({"max-height":"200px","max-width":"300px"}).appendTo(divId);

                               const options = {
                                    targetSize: 0.2,
                                    quality: 0.75,
                                    maxWidth: 800,
                                    maxHeight: 600
                                        }
                                        const compress = new Compress(options)


                                const files = [...input.files]
                                                // const files = [evt.files];
                                compress.compress(files).then((conversions) => {
                                // Conversions is an array of objects like { photo, info }.
                                // 'photo' has the photo data while 'info' contains metadata
                                // about that particular image compression (e.g. time taken).

                                const { photo, info } = conversions[0]

                                console.log({ photo, info })

                                //to append to the form data
                                newblob+i = photo.data;
                                // Create an object URL which points to the photo Blob data
                                const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(photo.data)

                                // Set the preview img src to the object URL and wait for it to load
                                Compress.loadImageElement(preview+i, objectUrl).then(() => {
                                    // Revoke the object URL to free up memory
                                    // URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
                                })
                                })                               

            }




        }

    };

    $('#image').on('change', function(evt) {
        imgPreviewUpld(this, 'div.previewdiv');




    });
});
```

Please guys help me. I am a beginner in javascript world but i want to do this for one of my own project.

Thank you

Comment: Most image formats (eg, .jpg) are already compressed.  Perhaps you meant "scaling", wherein the image is made smaller?  If you compress and uncompress a jpg, it will slow down the processing and save virtually no bandwidth.

Comment: this compress.js api works on client side so it has nothing to do with bandwidth. Also, it reduces the file size of any image to a great extent which saves a lot of bandwidth and upload time. I have tested this api with an image of size 10 MB, the result was unbelievable, reduced to around 150 KB with minimal loss in its quality. Nowadays images from any smartphone has an average file size of around 4-6 MB, if its uploaded to server without compression it will eat too much bandwidth and upload time will also be high. this api reduces those image to around 60-70 KB with minimal loss of quality

Comment: @RickJames i am not familiar with const and objects in JS. So i am having problem with passing multiple image in that and storing the compressed ones.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by that package's _misuse_ of the word "compress".  It seems to be an image "scaling" package.  And, sure, the example in the documentation shrank from too big to too small, thereby shrinking the disk size by 98%.  (I can't help with your Question.)

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?